# посчитать кол-во нулей в числе Python

Tags: python

Eсть вот такой кусок кода
надо чтобы он при вводе числа в котором есть ноль, выдавал это кол-во нулей

```
def zero(value):
    x = 0
    if  value == '0':
        print(x)
        x = x + 1

F = input()

zero(F)
```

Не могу понять, что надо исправить

Comment: `return value.count('0')`

Comment: @ entithat в какую часть кода мне надо это вписать?

Comment: Вместо всего тела функции

Answer (score 6):

```
def count_zeroes(n):
    return str(n).count('0')
```

Answer (score 4):

Если по честному работать с числом, то нужно делить:

```
def foo(n):
    if n < 0: 
        return foo(-n)
    i = 0
    while n:
        i += n % 10 == 0
        n //= 10
    return i

assert 3 == foo(10230240)
```

Для строки можно так:

```
def sfoo(sn):
    # if sn[0] == '-': return sfoo(sn[1:])
    # return sn.count('0')
    # len([*filterfalse(int, sn)])
    # return len([1 for d in sn if d == '0'])
    # return sum(d == '0' for d in sn)

    i = 0
    for d in sn:
        i += d == '0'

    return i

assert 3 == sfoo('10230240')
```

Answer (score 4):

если надо работать только с числом:

```
num = -10203040506070809

count = 0
value = abs(num)

while value != 0:
    count += int(value % 10 == 0)
    value //= 10

print(count)
```

абсолютное значение берется, потому что `-1 // 10 = -1` и цикл будет бесконечным для отрицательных чисел

если можно работать со строкой:

```
num = -10203040506070809

count = str(num).count('0')

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(n):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x == "0", str(n))))
```

Comment: Это уже перебор)))